# Select with values and IDs inside an ag-grid cell?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-valuesetter

I am very new to ag-grid and am evaluating it.

My project's data has multiple lookup tables (i.e. A Foo has a category of Bar, a Brand of Baz and a Class of Boo) that I would like to be able to edit in the ag-grid.  Unfortunately, those lookup tables are not in my control and I do not always have sequential IDs.

Example:

Foo has a Class

Class can be one of the following:

- ID -  Value
- 2  -  Test
- 3  -  UAT
- 6  -  Unknown
- 9  -  Production
- 15 -  Development

I can't control the IDs or the Values.

So if I put in the agSelectCellEditor, can I somehow tell it to display the values, but collect the IDs?

Has someone else got a better idea on how I can collect the Class, Brand, etc?

ETA:

From the ag-grid site (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#agselectcelleditor-agpopupselectcelleditor):

```
colDef.cellEditor = 'agSelectCellEditor';
colDef.cellEditorParams = {
    values: ['English', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Portuguese', '(other)']
}
```

This is what I've tried, but I can't get the IDs back out here.  Maybe someone else has a better idea or has implemented this before.

Thank you for helping an ag-grid noob.

Comment: please share sample code what you have tried or implemented

Comment: I haven't tried much--as I said, I'm evaluating the product.  Ag-grid claims that they support the agSelectCellEditor, but they don't show values and IDs.  Unfortunately, the company "support" only links here, rather than to them.

Comment: Are you trying to access grid data ,  ?? ID means key value???  key values are nothing but the columnDefinitions

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by creating a custom cell editor.

Component:

drop.down.editor.ts

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";

import {ICellEditorAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown-cell-editor',
    templateUrl: "drop.down.editor.html"
})
export class DropDownEditor implements ICellEditorAngularComp, AfterViewInit {
    private params: any;
    public value: number;
    private options: any;

    @ViewChild('input', {read: ViewContainerRef}) public input;


    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
        this.value = this.params.value;
        this.options = params.options;

    }

    getValue(): any {
        return this.value;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.input.element.nativeElement.focus();
        })
    }

}
```

drop.down.editor.html

```
 <select  #input  [(ngModel)]="value">
   <option *ngFor="let item of options" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</option>
  </select>
```

then add the module declaration

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ... , AgGridModule.withComponents( [DropDownEditor]) ],
  declarations: [ ..., DropDownEditor ]
})
```

then  use it in the column definition

```
{
    headerName: "Drop down",
    field: "dropdown",
    cellEditorFramework: DropDownEditor,
    editable: true,
    cellEditorParams: {
        options: [{
                name: "First Option",
                value: 1
            },
            {
                name: "Second Option",
                value: 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Full example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-1omhdt)

Comment: Currently, dropdown is hiding once, an item is selected and it resolves the value (not name) because we are returning this.value in getValue(). But how do I fix the dropdown? Meaning dropdown should stay visible in the cell at all time, whether the item is selected or not.

Comment: Another AG-Grid noob here, sorry about that.


If I understand correctly, the example above is in Angular, right?
Can it be transposed to plain vanilla Javascript?

(sorry, I'm also a newbie in javascript, and I cannot use angular on the project I'm working on)

Comment: @Pierre Yes, it is possible to rewrite this in plain javascript, you can look at the examples on the documentation which has custom cell editors in js