# ag-grid : how to set value in dropdown of ag-grid in angular while data is coming as key value

Tags: angular, angular8, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Here is the complete scenario,

I am getting some data from backend which I can show on ag-grid successfully, not this ag-grid is editable. user can change the information and I have to read that detail.

so from backend, i am getting data like this, i can reverse the order of data if required.

```
"test":{"test1":"test2","test3":"test4"}
```

here is the code of dropdown I am using in ag-grid

```
this.columns[i] = {
        headerName: 'abc',
        field: 'abc',
        width: 110,
        cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
        keyCreator: function (op) {
          return op.name;
        },
        cellEditorParams: {
          cellRenderer: 'dropDownCellRenderer',
          cellHeight: 30,
          values: this.dropDownList ///['a','b','c']
        },
        editable: true
      };
```

right now this.dropDownList is coming in dropdown but it is a arraylist and as defined above I want to select the key and when I read it it should display the value for that corresponding key.

but not sure how to replace that list from map

Comment: create stackblitz if possible.

Comment: not sure how to add dependency for ag-grid there

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular fork this and add your code there.

Comment: you need to create a custom `cellRenderer`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048083/select-with-values-and-ids-inside-an-ag-grid-cell) question as it answers your question.